# Constrains different on iPhone 4 and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout

I have this layout when running it on an iPhone 6, which is EXACTLY what i want:
[image]

However, here it is when running on the iPhone 4S (or on the iPad):
[image]

I really can't wrap my head around this. As you can see, the above picture has the text leaving the area, and the image being "shrunken". It is as if, the first image has the image resizing itself, and in the latter the text is filling up the blank space. How do i fix this?

**EDIT**
Here are the constraints for the left-side image, and the right-side table:

Left image:
[image]

Right table:
[image]

And here they are selected in IB:
[image]

Comment: You need to show the constraints and describe how the image views are configured. There are more visual issues than just the labels...

Comment: What constraints are on your labels? The spacing between the left side of the labels and the right side of the image looks consistent on both images. What constraints are on the image? It looks as though the width has scaled in proportion to the size of the displays.

Answer (score 0):

am not sure what you are doing with other elements but for the table and image i can suggest you those constraints. first clear all constraints of these two element and then try those.

for table in right side -

```
top to superview
bottom to superview
width - fixed
trailing to superview
```

for image on left

```
top to superview
bottom to superview
leading to superview
trailing to superview
```

put constraint values are according to your design. this will keep the right side table fixed width and resize the image to fill the rest of gap. i think this will solve your problem.

Comment: sorry, but that doesn't fix it :( Same issue, no change.

Answer (score 0):

So, it's a little hard without being able to try out the layout myself, but here's what I think you need to do:

- On your left image, **remove** the "Trailing Space To Superview" constraint.
- On your right tableview, **add** a Width constraint, constraining the table to its current width.

This means the text in the table will stay in the same location, and the left image will grow or shrink depending on the space available.